# Convert RTMP to RTSP & Stream

Tags: rtsp, rtmp

I am trying to stream the camera view from a React Native or Ionic app and then receive the output as an RTSP feed on my PC. I have been able to use Bambuser's SDK to stream to their servers, and from there I can output to RTMP. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to allow RTSP output.

Can anyone tell me the best way of receiving this RTMP stream & converting it to RTSP please? I can use the nginx RTMP module (https://hub.docker.com/r/tiangolo/nginx-rtmp/) but I am not sure how to convert to RTSP.

I've tried using Wowza for this instead which works great, but there is an error when trying to use their SDK on Vuzix Blade smart glasses which I am using so I am having to look for an alternative solution.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151067/react-native-stream-camera-of-android-phone-output-to-rtsp/61094529#61094529).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this by using MistServer in the end. It accepts a wide range of protocols including RTMP, and can output RTSP.