# React Native stream camera of Android phone output to RTSP

Tags: android, react-native, rtsp

I would like to stream my Android phone camera to a server, but my server only accepts RTSP. I have tried using react-native-nodemediaclient output RTMP which working well, but I don't want to write a RTMP to RTSP converter which is not optimal solution. So is there any way to implement it, I have searched Google but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Greetings.  You mention that you are using 'react-native-nodemediaclient' to stream RTMP from your device.  I am trying to do the same thing however I am running into difficulties.  Do you have any code sample that demonstrates this functionality I might be able to view?  I thank you in advance.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library [react-native-vlc-player](https://github.com/razorRun/react-native-vlc-media-player) to stream rtsp

Example

```
<View style={styles.body}>
        <VLCPlayer
          ref={(ref) => (this.vlcPlayer = ref)}
          style={{width: '100%', height: 200}}
          videoAspectRatio="16:9"
          source={{
            uri:
              'rtsp://admin:pass@IP:554/Streaming/Channels/102',
          }}
        />
      </View>
```