# Video stream receive in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video-streaming, rtsp

I have a video stream from my home camera on [rtsp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) protocol. Is it possible to play it on ios and android? I am trying to create

Versions:

- npm: 6.13.4
- node: v12.14.0
- react: ^16.12.0
- react-native: 0.61.5

I have tried packages:

- react-native-vlc-player
- react-native-vlcplayer
- react-native-video -> on is the app crashes because of SIGABRT
- react-native-live-stream -> this is always throwing build fail exceptions.

None of them working for me ...

I ran it in VLC Player on the computer, but not in the app.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59151067/react-native-stream-camera-of-android-phone-output-to-rtsp/61094529#61094529).

Comment: have you found something working ? I am looking for a good solution

Comment: I did ... Use WebView

Comment: Can you be more specific? I have install this: `npm i webview` but my stream from my web camera does not show up, but video for YouTube plays nicely @Hajan